# C language - strcmp returns 0 always and strcpy not copying the string in another array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to run this code where I enter two strings and user put the option for performing the following task.

After I enter `'a'` in the menu, the statement `strcpy(s_1,s_2);` the string is copied to `s_1` but when I added

```
#include <string.h>
```

it asked me to use `strcpy_s()` which I did and code stopped working.

When I enter `'b'` in the menu, I get only one output

```
Both Strings are equal to each other
```

I don't understand why `strcmp()` returns `0` always.

It would be great if someone help me out in this issue.

By the way I'm using *Visual Studio 2015* for compiling my C code.

```
#include< stdio.h>
#include< string.h>
#include< stdlib.h>
#include< process.h>

//USER-DEFINED FUNCTIONS

char top_down();

char copy_function();

char compare_function();

//char adder_function();

void header(void);

#define MAX 1000

void header()
{
  printf("*-*-*-*-*TASK_PERFORMER*-*-*-*-*");
  printf("\n\n");
}

//PROGRAM STARTS HERE
main()
{

  //VARIABLE DECLARATION
  char x =
  { 0 };

  //HEADING FUNCTION
  header();

  //USER-DEFINED FUNCTION CONSISTING OF ALL INPUTS.
  top_down();

  //TERMINAL-PAUSE
  system("pause");
}

char top_down()
{
  char s1[MAX] =
  { 0 }, s2[MAX] =
  { 0 }, x =
  { 0 };

  printf("Enter the First String : \n");
  fgets(s1, MAX, stdin);

  printf("\n");

  printf("The Entered First String : \n");
  printf("%s", s1);

  printf("\n");

  printf("Enter the Second String : \n");
  fgets(s2, MAX, stdin);

  printf("\n");

  printf("The Entered Second String : \n");
  printf("%s", s2);

  printf("\n");
  printf("*-*-*-TYPE ANY OPTION TO PERFORM TASK-*-*-*");
  printf("\n");

  //GIVEN OPTIONS FOR SELECTOR
  printf("Enter one option from the following : \n\n");
  printf("(a) To Copy one string to another. \n");
  printf("(b) To Compare two string. \n");
  printf("(c) To Add a string to the end of another string. \n");
  printf("\n");

  repeat:

  printf("Enter Your Option : \n");

  scanf_s("%c", &x);
  printf("\n");

  //OPTION-SELECTOR
  switch (x)
  {
  case 'a':

    copy_function(s1, s2);
    break;

  case 'b':

    compare_function(s1, s1);
    break;

  case 'c':

    //adder_function(s1, s2);
    break;

  default:
    printf("INVALID OPTION \n");
    printf("Please Try Again \n");
    goto repeat;
    break;

    return;
  }
}

char copy_function(char s_1[], char s_2[])
{
  int x = 0;

  x = strlen(s_2);

  printf("Second String will be copied to First string now \n");
  //strcpy(s_1, s_2);
  strcpy_s(s_1, x, s_2);

  printf("\n");

  printf("First String Output : \n");
  printf("%s", s_1);

  return;
}

char compare_function(char s_1[], char s_2[])
{

  int a = 0, l1 = 0, l2 = 0, i = 0;

  printf("First String will be compared to Second String now \n ");

  //printf("\n");

  if (strcmp(s_1, s_2) == 0)
    printf("Both String are equal to each other \n");

  else if (strcmp(s_1, s_2) > 0)
    printf("First String is greater than Second String");

  else
    printf("First String is lesser than Second String \n");

  return;
}
```

Comment: You have to pass the number of elements of **destination buffer** to `strcpy_s()`. [strcpy_s, wcscpy_s, _mbscpy_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx)

Comment: Kindly check what is returned by strcpy_s(). If zero then ur code ok and if any other value that would be error number

Comment: In your call to compare_function you have passed s1 for both strings to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your program is in progress. I modified it and removed anything I thought was not necessary.

- The functions' signatures change to `void`
- Removed `x` in `main`
- Return type of `main` set to `int` (It is `int` by default, but this spares you the warning of the compiler)
- I work on Linux, so I removed the `system(...)`, feel free to add it.
- Only left variables declarations in `top_down` (not important, but an initial value should have a meaning and in your case there is no meaning to `0`)
- Changed `scanf_s("%c", &x);` to `scanf(" %c", &x);` (note the space. not sure if on windows that makes a difference. please check.)
- Changed the function call `compare_function(s1, s1);` to `compare_function(s1, s2);`
- Removed the `return` statements in the `void` functions
- In `copy_function` I removed `int x = 0;` and `x = strlen(s_2);`
- In `copy_function` I changed `strcpy_s(s_1, x, s_2);` to `strcpy(s_1, s_2);`
- In `compare_function` I removed `int a = 0, l1 = 0, l2 = 0, i = 0;`

You use *label*/*goto*. That's ok, but considered not cool nowadays. You could use a loop and break in case of an invalid option.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//USER-DEFINED FUNCTIONS
void top_down();
void copy_function();
void compare_function();
//char adder_function();
void header(void);

#define MAX 1000

void header() {
    printf("*-*-*-*-*TASK_PERFORMER*-*-*-*-*");
    printf("\n\n");
}

//PROGRAM STARTS HERE
int main() {

    //HEADING FUNCTION
    header();
    //USER-DEFINED FUNCTION CONSISTING OF ALL INPUTS.
    top_down();

    return 0;
}

void top_down() {

    char s1[MAX], s2[MAX], x;

    printf("Enter the First String : \n");
    fgets(s1, MAX, stdin);

    printf("\n");

    printf("The Entered First String : \n");
    printf("%s", s1);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter the Second String : \n");
    fgets(s2, MAX, stdin);

    printf("\n");

    printf("The Entered Second String : \n");
    printf("%s", s2);

    printf("\n");
    printf("*-*-*-TYPE ANY OPTION TO PERFORM TASK-*-*-*");
    printf("\n");

    //GIVEN OPTIONS FOR SELECTOR
    printf("Enter one option from the following : \n\n");
    printf("(a) To Copy one string to another. \n");
    printf("(b) To Compare two string. \n");
    printf("(c) To Add a string to the end of another string. \n");
    printf("\n");

repeat:

    printf("Enter Your Option : \n");
    scanf(" %c", &x);
    printf("\n");

    //OPTION-SELECTOR
    switch (x) {
        case 'a':
            copy_function(s1, s2);
            break;
        case 'b':
            compare_function(s1, s2);
            break;
        case 'c':
            //adder_function(s1, s2);
            break;
        default:
            printf("INVALID OPTION \n");
            printf("Please Try Again \n");
            goto repeat;
            break;

    }

}

void copy_function(char s_1[], char s_2[]) {

    printf("Second String will be copied to First string now \n");
    strcpy(s_1, s_2);

    printf("\n");

    printf("First String Output : \n");
    printf("%s", s_1);

}

void compare_function(char s_1[], char s_2[]) {

    printf("First String will be compared to Second String now \n ");

    if (strcmp(s_1, s_2) == 0)
        printf("Both String are equal to each other \n");
    else if (strcmp(s_1, s_2) > 0)
        printf("First String is greater than Second String");
    else
        printf("First String is lesser than Second String \n");

}
```

Comment: compare_function was not working because instead of typing " compare_function(s1, s2); " I typed "compare_function(s1, s1); ". I tried your code in visual studio and it is working when I compared the strings but when I type option ' a ' in menu it gives me error asking me to use " strcpy_s " which I did and its not working. If I remove " #include<string.h> " strcpy starts working without any errors. In my previous code I used strcpy_s which was not working either if I have made any mistake in it please correct me.

Thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to remove `#include <string.h>` entirely if you don't need it and simply use `strcpy(..., ...)`? Does that work? If not, then why?

Comment: I'm fine without using #include<string.h> but I would like to know why strcpy_s not working ( I'm using Visual Studio 2015 btw )

Comment: I don't know really. I would use as second parameter the size of the destination buffer, something like `sizeof(s2[MAX])` for example... Try and see...